# How to use injected dataSource in Grails to perform operations?

Tags: hibernate, grails

Is there a way to use an injected datasource in grails for specific operations such as .createCriteria() , .list(), and .find()?

I have tried the following:

```
def dataSource_test //Injected dataSource

DomainClass.dataSource_test.createCriteria() //returns no property for domain class
DomainClass.createCriteria(dataSource_test) //returns no matching method for argument
```

I know it is possible to do the following way:

```
DomainClass.test.createCriteria()
```

This way however gives me more issues, linked here: [Validation using wrong datasource when using multiple datasources in Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549004/table-not-found-when-using-multiple-datasources-in-grails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to use an injected datasource in grails for specific
>   operations such as .createCriteria() , .list(), and .find()?

No.  We support multiple datasources and provide a mechanism for expressing which datasource you want a particular query to be associate with, but that isn't what you are asking about.  We do not provide a way for you to associate GORM methods with a data source that you have injected into an artifact.

Comment: Thank you for the information Jeff.  If you happen to have a chance can you perhaps help me figure out why I'm having the other issue posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549004/table-not-found-when-using-multiple-datasources-in-grails

Comment: @Jeff-scott-brown - is there a way to have criteria use the datasource specified in Domain class mapping by default ? - For example my domain class has datasource "lookup" in mapping block. but still, criteria queries does not work unless i do Domain.lookup.createCriteria() - however Domain.list() works as expected. I am using grails 2.4.4